# Remote Powershell popup message

Tags: powershell, vbscript, scripting, wsh

I'm attempting to create a remote powershell popup window to any users logged into a target computer.

I have found a simple script that does create a popup window:

```
(New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell).popup("THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE")
```

However, I cannot run this script on remote devices. We have powershell remoting restricted in our environment so I cannot use the invoke-command cmdlet in powershell.

I have bypassed this restriction in the past by using the Invoke-WmiMethod cmdlet and creating a new process remotely to achieve the desired results, like such:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer -Name Create -ArgumentList "C:\Program Files\Test\Test.exe -argument"
```

However, I cannot seem to find a way to generate a remote popup window using this method.

Does anybody have any great ideas on how I can accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out. I used the msg.exe application to display my message and used powershell Invoke-WmiMethod to execute the command locally on the PC as we have remote messaging disabled:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName HostPC -Name Create -ArgumentList "C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe * This is a test message."
```

Answer (score 2):

I edited the script samples above with Powershell to make it easier to run with variables so you don't have to edit the file every time.

```
$server = read-host -prompt 'Input server name';
$message = read-host -prompt 'add text string'; 
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class win32_process -ComputerName $server -Name create -ArgumentList  "c:\windows\system32\msg.exe * $message"
```

Thanks to [Maumee River](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689582/maumee-river) for the original answer