# Handle hidden popup in remote powershell msiexec installation

Tags: windows, powershell, popup, remote-access, windows-installer

I need to perform upgrading of applications remotely via powershell. Uninstall works fine, but because for installation, there is a popup that requires me to click on "ok" before proceeding. While I could shut that down in the local installation instance, I can't do that for remote installations as that popup is hidden (not shown). My installation thus fails. Here's my script:

```
Enter-PSSession "computername" -Auth CredSSP -cred username
(Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i D:\path\installer.msi /l*vx D:\path\installation.log /q" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```

The execution of the above script hangs because of the hidden popup. Any ideas on how I can suppress the hidden popup or send a 'enter' instruction, preferably without using psexec?

Resources I already referenced: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013411/remote-powershell-popup-message) | [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358626/msiexec-silent-mode-installation) | [3](https://weblogs.asp.net/ashrafurrahaman/powershell-remote-execution) | [4](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4c8fad53-d7ad-4e9a-9569-454d9c793bd3/powershell-to-close-a-running-program-gracefully-without-uses-interact?forum=w7itprogeneral) | [5](https://superuser.com/questions/351487/running-msiexec-with-powershell) | [6](http://www.fixitscripts.com/problems/automated-program-install-via-remote-command-line) |

Comment: to simulate on your machine, just do a enter-pssession, then "msiexec". By default, that opens up a dialog, and would be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Maybe it was a corner case that the solution might work only for my case, but I'll share it in case others wish to try out (`/LM/W3SVC/2` and `<appPool name>` and other paths need to be changed accordingly to your setup):

### Old Script

```
msiexec /i  D:\path\installer.msi TARGETAPPPOOL=<appPool name> TARGETSITE=/LM/W3SVC/2 /l*vx D:\path\installation.log /quiet
```

The popup persists, even with /quiet or /qn. It's made worse when it's hidden if executed remotely. But I chanced upon setting the `TARGETDIR` and the popup was acknowledged automatically and taken care of:

### New Script

```
msiexec /i  D:\path\installer.msi TARGETAPPPOOL=<appPool name> TARGETDIR=D:\path TARGETSITE=/LM/W3SVC/2 /l*vx D:\path\installation.log /quiet
```

The new **property** attribute seems unrelated to my problem, but nonetheless solved it.